# Как получить список ip адресов всех активных сетевых адаптеров в windows?

Tags: windows

Как получить список ip адресов всех активных сетевых адаптеров в windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого необходимо открыть терминал и выполнить команду

```
ipconfig
```